# Function extensionality in Dafny

Tags: dafny

How can we prove that if for all inputs, `f` and `g` returns the same output, then the two functions are equivalent?

```
lemma func_ext(f: int -> int, g: int -> int)
requires forall x :: f(x) == g(x)
ensures f == g
```

I would assume this is an axiom but it does not work. Is function extensionality not true in Dafny?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think dafny supports function extensionality. I didn't find anything in official documentation but here is link to comment which
confirms this https://github.com/dafny-lang/dafny/issues/2308#issuecomment-1169553777

> We do not have functional extensionality in Dafny's theory. I asked @RustanLeino about it recently, and he thought it would be non-trivial to add. Part of the issue is that lambdas can read the heap, so pointwise equality without considering the heap is not enough.

Comment: OH! That would make a lot of proof more annoying in Dafny without adding it as an axiom manually.

Answer (score 1):

There is no extensionality for functions. One big reason for that is that "==" is not translated with a type yet.

So for example take:

```
var f: int -> int = (x: int) => x;
var g: int -> int = (x: int) => if x >= 0 then x else -x;

var fp: nat -> int = f;
var gp: nat -> int = g;
assert forall x: nat :: fp(x) == gp(x);
assert fp == gp; // Suppose we had extensionality
assert f == g;   // Because fp == f and gp == g
assert -1 == f(-1) == g(-1) == 1;
assert false;
```

This would go away if only we could have equality according to a type, though.

Comment: I feel like the way subtyping work is weird. I would expect the third line that assigns `f` to `fp`(same for `g` and `gp`), would add an requirement to `fp` such that it would only accept positive integer as input, so `f` and `fp` should not be equal.

Comment: A function that takes an integer as input is also a function that takes a positive integer as input.
Like a mixer that can mix fruits is a mixer that can mix apples. But it's the same mixer, whether I give it to a multifruit juice competition or an apple juice competition.

What you would probably like to say and add is similar to what I'm suggesting. When declaring equality, fp and f are equal on the domain of `nat`, and that information should be carried somewhere. That way, we would be able to express that f and g are also equal if restricted to the "nat" input type.

Comment: But a mixer can mix apples may not mix fruits (at least in maths). I think I didn't make it clear enough. What I was thinking is that there is a `coerce` function that turn a function with type `int -> int` to type `nat -> int` inserted by the encoder automatically when doing the subtyping. What `coerce` does is basically adding the assumption that the input must be positive. While I disagree that `f == fp` , I agree that `coerce(f) == fp`.

Comment: If the smt solver is aware of the `coerce` function, then we would not have `f == g` which causes the unsoundness, as we can only say `coerce(f) == coerce(g)` (or `f: nat -> int == g`), but not `f == g`. I am not sure if this is what you mean by "equality according to type", but it seems like this can done solely by the term if this is how subtyping is done. I don't know how smt encoding works and how Dafny deals with subtyping, but it seems like this should work. Would you like to explain how subtyping encoded by Dafny? And is there any problem/complications with this idea?

Comment: A mixer that can mix apples (nat -> int) cannot mix fruits (int -> int). But a mixer that can mix fruits (int -> int) is a mixer that can mix apples (nat -> int). This argument states that f:int -> int is also a f:nat -> int without any need for coercion or extra assumption.

Comment: Dafny does not have such a coerce function by the way. But the fundamental problem is really the unrestricted equality

Comment: Regarding the first response, my argument is that `fp = f` ,  if you consider the domain `nat`. However, f have `int` as the domain, not `nat`, so I think they should not consider as the same. You need something that restrict the domain of `f` like `coerce`, to say that they are equal in the domain of `nat`. 
Regarding the second response, how does Dafny do subtyping then? Does it just tell the smt solver `fp = f` when there is `var fp: nat -> int = f`?

Comment: Yes exactly, it uses unrestricted equality, which is the source of problems. If we added the type to the equality there would be no problem.

Comment: By the way, the fundamental issue is: are function types part of the function values? If types are contracts, then f == fp because they were assigned the same value (a lambda that can compute something), it's just they are used under different contracts. On the other hand, if you consider a function value as not just the computation but also the contract, then you're right, there would be a coercion function.

Comment: Similar to having fNat = Function(computation: Computation, inputs: set<Nat>, outputs: set<Int>) is not the same as fInt = Function(computation: Computation, inputs: set<Int>, outputs: set<Int>), and in that case you would neither be able to cast an fInt to a fNat or a fNat to an fInt (invariance), the first if which was the interesting case of my previous message that you ought to be able to do.